# Abbreviation for $n$ times differentiable, with $n$th derivative bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, notation

Are there convenient abbreviations in use for the following sets?

1. The set of functions which are $n$ times differentiable, with first $n-1$ derivatives continuous (obviously the last part is redundant).
2. The set of functions which are $n$ times differentiable, with the $n$th derivative bounded.

Comment: For question $1$, I believe I have seen the notation $C^n$...

Comment: I believe $C^n$ implies that the $n$th derivative is continuous, right?

Comment: I've never heard of an abbreviation for either.  I agree with Eric's comment.